# What's correct - Conflict of OR Conflict between?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentences would be the right usage here?

> 1. Conflict **of** ABC and XYZ
> 2. Conflict **between** ABC and XYZ

Answer (score 1):

Number 2, "Conflict **between** (a number of parties)".

Using the "Conflict **of** ..." is typically when describing a "conflict of interest" this is (per Wikipedia's concise definition) " a situation in which a person or organisation is involved in multiple interests, financial or otherwise, in situations where serving one the interests could involve working against one of the other interests. "